Is it wrong that I found negative key d for key (n, e) (RSA encryption)?
I struggled to solve a cryptography problem which looks like following:
"What is the original message encrypted using the RSA system with n = 53·61 and e = 17 if the encrypted message is 3185 2038 2460 2550? (To decrypt, first find the decryption exponent d, which is the inverse of e = 17 modulo 52 · 60.)"
I used the extended euclidean algorithm but somehow got a negative value for d = -367 and the modular exponent algorithm needs the exponent to be positive. I didn't know where things went wrong.
This is my program (just ignore those couts for debugging, tks):
int xGCD( int a, int b, int &x, int &y ) {
    if( b == 0 ) {
       x = 1;
       y = 0;
       cout << "x=" << x <<' ' <<"y="<< y <<' '<<"a="<< a <<'\n';
       return a;  
    }

    int x1, y1, gcd = xGCD( b, a % b, x1, y1 );
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - ( a / b ) * y1;
    cout <<"x="<< x <<' '<<"y="<< y <<' ' <<"gcd="<< gcd <<'\n';
    return gcd;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 17, b = 3120, x, y, gcd;

   gcd = xGCD( a, b, x, y );
   cout << "GCD: " << gcd << ", x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';

   return 0;
}

Here is the output: GCD: 1, x = -367, y = 2

The extended euclidean algorithm (xGCD) can correctly return a negative number, that's why xGCD is only the first part of the algorithm to find the inverse of a mod t. The second step is adding t to the output of the xGCD if the result is negative. Note that, mathematically, the negative number is not incorrect, and may even work just fine in your implementation depending on how you implemented it.

Thank you! It works now, and the answer is "squirrel".
